# Simple JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript

Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
window.onload = initForm;
function initForm() {
    var allTags = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for(i=0; i<allTags.length; i++) {
        if (allTags[i].className.indexOf("textbox") > -1) {
            allTags[i].onFocus = fieldSelect;
            allTags[i].onBlur = fieldDeSelect;          
        }
    }
}
function fieldSelect() {
    this.style.backgroundImage = "url('inputBackSelected.png')";
}

function fieldDeSelect() {
    this.style.backgroundImage = "url('inputBack.png')";
}
```

I am a beginner at JavaScript so I am not used to debugging code yet.

Thanks

Luke

Comment: what specifically isnt working, and are you getting an error?

Comment: Are you sure that's the right path to your `.png` images? They're not in a `images/` directory or something?

Comment: What are you trying to do in first place? Does that comes with an HTML file or something?

Comment: Use something like fiddler or http analyzer to watch for 404s trying to retrieve your images.  The javascript looks ok.  I would change the loop though.  `for(i=0; i<allTags.length; i++) ` place allTags.length in a different variable and use that, otherwise on every iteration of your for loop, javascript checks the allTags.length, which with large collections can be VERY slow

Comment: Don't forget to select an answer if you found one helpful. Click the green check mark.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem lies in attaching your event handlers.  You should bind to `onfocus` and `onblur` (note the lowercase event name).

As a suggestion, you may want to look at a very simple cross browser [`addEvent()`](http://www.scottandrew.com/weblog/articles/cbs-events) with a quick line of code added to ensure the proper `this` pointer:

```
function addEvent(obj, evType, fn, useCapture){
  if (obj.addEventListener){
    obj.addEventListener(evType, fn, useCapture);
    return true;
  } else if (obj.attachEvent){
    // fix added by me to handle the `this` issue
    var r = obj.attachEvent("on"+evType, function(){ 
      retrun fn.apply(obj, arguments); 
    });
    return r;
  } else {
    alert("Handler could not be attached");
  }
}
```

And then use the `addEvent` function instead of `allTags[i].onfocus =` you will probably have better mileage in the future binding events.

```
addEvent(allTags[i], 'focus', fieldSelect);
addEvent(allTags[i], 'blur', fieldDeSelect);
```

[jsfiddle demonstration](http://www.jsfiddle.net/bg76K/2)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when `fieldSelect` and `fieldDeselect` are getting called, `this` refers to the `window` object, not to the element that fired the event. You might want to consider using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.textbox').focus(fieldSelect).blur(fieldDeselect);
});

function fieldSelect() {
    $(this).css('background-image', 'url("inputBackSelected.png")');
}

function fieldDeselect() {
    $(this).css('background-image', 'url("inputBack.png")');
}
```

jQuery takes care of making sure that when your event handlers are getting called, `this` refers to the element that fired the event.

Answer (score 1):

Two things, the events should be all lower case (`onfocus`, `onblur`) and `this` doesn't point to the object that triggered the event in IE. Try this:

```
function fieldSelect(e) {
    var event;
    if(!e) {
        event = window.event;
    } else {
        event = e;
    }
    event.target.style.backgroundImage = "url('inputBackSelected.png')"; 
} 

function fieldDeSelect(e) {
    var event;
    if(!e) {
        event = window.event;
    } else {
        event = e;
    }
    event.target.style.backgroundImage = "url('inputBack.png')"; 
}
```

Standards complient browsers will pass an event object to the event handler. IE uses a global `window.event` object instead. Either way you can use that object to get the target of the event that triggered the handler.

Another, probably preferable option would be to have your functions set and remove a `className` instead of directly changing the style. Then put a style called maybe `selected` in your stylesheet that overrides the background image. That way you keep style info and behavior separate.

Comment: `e = e || window.event;` is a quick way to ensure the proper event object in `e`.   If `e` is falsy (undefined/0/''/etc) the JavaScript or operator `||` will result in `window.event` being assigned to `e`;

Comment: Thanks for the responses, It seems that the fact that I had onBlur instead of onblur meant that it didn't work. But neither firefox's firebig, nor chrome's inspector pointed this out. Anyway it works now, and also seems to work in IE 8. Not sure about other versions of IE though.

Comment: @Lukes123: Note that you can edit your comments. Also, don't forgot to mark an answer as accepted when it solved your problem (click the checkmark next to the answer).

Comment: JavaScript can't catch those kinds of errors because of the way it's objects work. You were actually assigning a new method called onBlur to each element, which is perfectly legal. The browser won't find it when an event fires, so it doesn't behave as you expect, but it's legal. It may seem frustrating at first, especially if you're coming from a "classicaly" OO language, but it's actually one of the best features of js.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of window.onload=initform try window.onload=function(){/*the init function/*}
Also when refering to a function you should use () even if there are no arguments.

Comment: Not true at all.  `window.onload=initform` is perfectly legal.  You are assigning the value of `window.onload` to be the `function initform`, if you were to add `()` it would immediately call that function and assign `window.onload` to the return value of `initform`.